# Unwrap with if var and still return cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, return, unwrap

I have a cellForRowAt indexPath method within a UITableViewController class where I'm trying to unwrap the variable 'tasks' (declared in another .swift file). If I unwrap it with if var and then return cell outside the scope of the if var, I get a "Use of unresolved identifier 'cell'" error, but if I include return cell within the scope of the if var, I get a "Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell'" error. How do I fix this? I'm just learning Swift so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if var tasks = exampleList.tasks {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell
        let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
            cell.task = task

        if cell.accessoryView == nil {
            let cb = CheckButton()
            cb.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:forEvent:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            cell.accessoryView = cb
        }

        let cb = cell.accessoryView as! CheckButton
        cb.check(tasks[indexPath.row].completed) //Replaced previous cb.check line with this per Stack Overflow James Baxter's advice

    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: **Never** use an optional array as data source in an `UITableViewController`. This is very bad habit. Declare the array as non-optional, copy the value of the external array in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` and reload the table view.

Comment: So where should I initialize the instance then? I want to have multiple instances of struct TaskList (multiple task lists shared individually with different friends) that the user can individually add to and toggle between.

Comment: To be clear, exampleList as seen in the code was an instance of TaskList and I was initializing it with "let exampleList = TaskList(..." as a property of class LoLFirstTableViewController

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but you can try this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    if var tasks = exampleList.tasks {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell
        let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
        cell.task = task

        if cell.accessoryView == nil {
            let cb = CheckButton()
            cb.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:forEvent:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            cell.accessoryView = cb
        }

        if let cb = cell.accessoryView as! CheckButton {
            cb.check(tasks[indexPath.row].completed) //Replaced previous cb.check line with this per Stack Overflow James Baxter's advice
        }

    }
    return cell
}
```

Remember that the tableView function must always return a *UITableViewCell* object, so even when the first *if* statement fails, you must provide a valid return! Read Apple's documentation about optional values, unwrapping etc. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You get this compiler error because you create the `cell` variable inside the `if` block; if that block is not entered (which would be the case if `exampleList.tasks` is `nil`), not `cell` is created and thus cannot be returned from the method.

To fix this, just move the line where you create the cell object to before the `if` block. Optionally you could also configure the cell to indicate that no data is present if the `if` is not entered:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell
if let tasks = exampleList.tasks {
  // configure cell with task
}
else {
  // configure cell WITHOUT task
}
return cell
```